# Obtaining a large amount of lava in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I want to use lava as a lighting system, but that will require a lot of lava. What's a good way to move a large amount of lava? I'd rather not make many buckets and have to travel back and forth. So far I think it's my only option since I don't think it's possible to make unlimited lava source blocks. Oh, and if it matters, I'm on the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to make infinite lava sources, (maybe) I think you just have to make a 4x4 lava pool.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Unless a lot has changed since I last checked (unlikely) infinite lava is not possible in vanilla minecraft for any platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to make infinite lava in the Xbox edition of Minecraft.

Your only option is to make buckets and carry it. To speed the process up, use more buckets and consider using the nether as a source of magma.

Comment: I didn't think about the nether. That will actually greatly help. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelBlake You're welcome. If you liked my answer, consider accepting it- we both get rep that way.

Comment: it won't let me accept it yet, but I will when I can.

Comment: It helps if you have a friend playing with you, and have at least two Ender chests. Stick one chest in the Nether, the other where you're working with the lava, and then set up a conveyor system. They fill the chest up with buckets then run to fill up a second set. You grab those in the meantime, empty them, and put the empties back in the chest. Quick way to fill up even a large glass / lava lighting system.

Answer (score -1):

Even natural lava pools in ANY kind of Minecraft I believe, are not infinite.
The only infinite lava is in the nether.
There are mods for everything, maybe there's one that lets you make infinite lava.

Comment: The nether doesn't have an 'infinite' amount of lava. Yes, it has an extremely high amount but same as the overworld it has a world limit and should you gather every source block of lava (since it cant replicate) you would rid the nether of all its lava.